# Help understand why this proof can be "easily extend" while it uses a property specific to 2-norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the standard inner product $〈\cdot〉$, the $\bf W$ norm for some matrix $\bf W$ is defined as $〈{\bf x},{\bf y}〉_{\bf W}=〈{\bf Wx},{\bf y}〉$.

Given an iteration ${{\mathbf{x}}^{i + 1}} = {{\mathbf{x}}^i} - {{\mathbf{W}}^{ - 1}}({\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{x}}^i} - {\mathbf{b}})$ to solve linear system ${\mathbf{Ax}} = {\mathbf{b}}$, the following says we can use a "relaxation" parameter $\alpha_0$ (let $\alpha_i$ in 1.20) and a modified iteration as

> ${{\mathbf{x}}^{i + 1}} = {{\mathbf{x}}^i} - {\alpha _0}{{\mathbf{W}}^{ - 1}}({\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{x}}^i} - {\mathbf{b}})$

to make the convergence fast. The problem is that I don't see why the proof holds for the $\bf W$-norm (), since the proof uses a property specific to 2-norm that it equals the maximum eigenvalue of $\bf A$ when $\bf A$ is Hermitian positive definite. Book link is [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=sBIPBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=iterative%20methods%20for%20linear%20systems&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji1dbDn-fWAhVINSYKHWOKBV0Q6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q&f=false) from page 11 to page 12.

> [image]
>   [image]